# tomcat7 hot-standby Node with mod-cluster and Apache HTTPD2.2

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-cluster, mod-proxy-balancer

I'm using tomcat7.0.63 with mod-cluster1.2.9 and Apache HTTPD2.2 on RHEL6.7

Multiple Tomcat-instances with dedicated balancer configurations are sharing the Apache HTTPD using dedicated Virtualhost:6666.
Only one Tomcat instance should have a Master-Node and a Hot-Standby Node. 
I tried with mod-proxy-balancer, BalancerMember, with and without ModClusterListener in server.xml. But it seens the coexistence with mod-cluster on a shared Apache HTTPD is not working...or I make a mistake.

```
ProxyPass / balancer://mycl/
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycl/
<Proxy balancer://mycl>
    BalancerMember ajp://1.2.3.9:8009 route=master retry=30
    # The server below is on hot standby
    BalancerMember ajp://1.2.3.4:8009 route=standby status=+H
</Proxy>
```

For JBoss EAP and Wildfly there is the lbfactor/loadfactor:

```
 <simple-load-provider factor="0"/>
```

which makes one node to a hot-standby node.

Is there a way to do so with tomcat7, e.g. a mod-cluster Tomcat system-property which sends a `load = 0` (standby) to `Virtualhost:6666` ?

kind regards, hplar